# Input field disabled, but glyphicon is still clickable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am writing a ReactJS application, and I want to disable the input on a date/time field, which includes the `react-bootstrap-datetimepicker`. Disabling the input field works fine, but the glyph used to bring up the datepicker, when clicked, is still active, and it allows the user to select a date, which is added to the input field. It just seems to prevent typing.

Does anyone know a way around this?

```
<DateTimeField
    inputFormat='HH:mm'
    data-hour-format="24"
    mode='time'
    name="formInputTime"
    id={inputID}
    defaultText={this._getICEField(i-1, "time")}
    onChange={this._generateEventHandler(i-1, "time")}
    inputProps={{disabled: readOnly}}
/>
```

In this image the input field is set as `disabled`, but the calendar still appears, and a date can be set:

[image]

Here is an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xb5vbbp1/).

Comment: added a jsfiddle to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the control does not support this as of now (and maybe it shouldn't either), so you should not run the

```
$element.datetimepicker()
```

on those input fields, which are disabled. You can check the disabled state programmticaly like this:

```
var $startDate = $('#startDate');
if (!$startDate.prop('disabled')) {
    $startDate.datetimepicker()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I have just updated your code: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xb5vbbp1/3/).

Relevant code:

```
if($("input[name=startDate]").attr('disabled') != 'disabled') {
    jQuery("#startDate").on("dp.change",function (e) {
        jQuery('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
    });       
    jQuery('#startDate').datetimepicker();
}
```

Comment: Please always provide the *code itself*, a jsfiddle is not enough.

Comment: @meskobalazs Thank you